# How to build, with smart pointers, a tree that survive the end of its scope

Tags: c++, memory-management, tree, smart-pointers

I need to build a tree which will be generated in a game loop. This tree has to stay in memory at the end of this loop, to be still available in the next iteration. In consequence, I have to use heap memory. I could use raw pointers and it would probably be fine. However, I read that in modern C++, one should use smart pointers instead; and smart pointers delete themselves when reaching end of scope.

To bypass this problem, I found an implementation where I store the smart pointers in a vector which is globally declared. And it works:

```
class Node;

vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>>childsList;

class Node
{
public:
  Node(int recursionLevel)
  {
    if (recursionLevel < 2)
    {
      childsList.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Node>(recursionLevel+1));
      childsList.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Node>(recursionLevel+1));
    }
  }
};


int main()
{

  { // This scope is the game loop. The tree has to survive to the end of this loop iteration.
    childsList.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Node>(0)); // Tree creation
  }

}
```

Is it the good way to do it? I feel like I'm doing it dirty, and that smart pointers are not made for this kind of job. Also, performance is important here.

Optional question: I noted that I could use push_back instead of emplace_back with no difference (no unique pointer object created on the stack before to be copied into the vector). Do push_back behave the same as emplace_back for unique_ptr?

Comment: There are two flavors of `std::vector::push_back()`: one with `const T&` and one with `T&&`. `std::make_unique<Node>()` provides an RValue which will trigger the `push_back(<std::unique_ptr<Node>>&&)` and that's good because otherwise the `push_back()` couldn't work - `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied.

Comment: _smart pointers are not made for this kind of job._ Smart pointers are made to replace raw pointers - specifically for pointers managing ownership. That's the case here, i.e. `std::unique_ptr` appears as a reasonable choice. Concerning the performance difference between emplace_back a unique_ptr vs. push_back a unique_ptr... Please, forget about this. If there is any performance difference it's surely marginale. I would be more concerned about the global vector (of all instances) which is modified in a constructor...

Comment: I checked your code on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed57aa24a8d8707e) and it seems to do what it's supposed to. So, maybe your question is better fitting in [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your answers Scheff. You made very interesting points. I'll post it on codereview, you're right. Have a very good day.

Comment: Link: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/274266/how-to-build-with-smart-pointers-a-tree-that-survive-the-end-of-its-scope